# Creating a row with onClick properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick, buttonclick

I'm using this code snippet from W3Schools to create a new row in my table:

```
// Find a <table> element with id="myTable":
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

// Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
var row = table.insertRow(0);

// Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

// Add some text to the new cells:
cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
```

After creating it, all the rows in the table have their onClick functions except the one I just created, so my question is, how can I specify an onClick function for that row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also use

```
document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML+="<tr onClick='myFunc();'></tr>"
```

---

or by your way you can use

```
row.onClick="myFunc();"
```

or

```
 row.setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: myFunc();" )
```

Comment: Couldn't get the first or second version to work, but the third one seemed to solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: actually that was by mistake i write the `cell1` in place of `row`

Answer (score 1):

Or add this event listener later:

```
var obj=document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0]
obj.onclick=function(){alert("whatever")};
```

where `[0]` 0= row number